# android facebook - Why key hash is different?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate the FB to android app. For this,I get the key hash using cmd tool in windows 7.

**command:**

```
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platform-tools>keytool -exportcert -alias
 andrpoiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\naresh.repalle\.android\debug.keystore" |
"C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" base64
```

**Enter keystore password:  android**

**BASE_64_HASH_1**

I set the key hash (from the `cmd`) to the app in the `fb developer` console and after try to run this in the device here i got the error as **remote_app_id does not match stored id.**

For Rechecking the key hash with developer console. I did some coding in my app. using this i get the key hash. i am trying to match these two key hashes but these are different. Because of this i set these two as key hashes but this time i got the error as "**No node specified**". Why these two key hashes are different? Why these error was occured. can anyone help me.

// Add code to print out the key hash

```
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.android.example", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Here i got the key hash as "BASE_64_ENCODED_HASH_2". I did this in the same machine. why these two key hashes are different?

Comment: Really a good question. I am also facing the same issue. Did you get the solution? And why facebook is not taking any action on this behalf. I really dont know.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I thought there was a step I was missing. My key hash won't work either. If you have a fix, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it only comes up *after* installing the Facebook app, before I did this I was developing fine and executing without setting any hashes at the FB app site. But after I installed the FB app, I tripped into this as well. As noted, the hashes from the FB recommended cmd string and from inside the code using that above are different.

But I added the hash as generated in the code and that seems to have cleared it up.